# Yii 2 Action load into facebook canvas (iframe) Getting http Error 400

Tags: php, facebook, canvas, facebook-php-sdk, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on a Facebook canvas application which is technically supposed to load a page from YII 2. I am using Facebook PHP SDK. However my current problem is that whenever I try to load the canvas, I get `error 400` (Unable to verify your data submission). On Facebook settings, I have the correct domain name on allowed domain.

Below is my source code and error:

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'=>$appId ,
    'app_secret'=>$appSecret,
    'default_graph_version'=>'v2.5']);$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
                    $permissions = ['email','user_likes','user_friends'];
                    try {
                                    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
                    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                            echo 'We are unable to log you in. Sorry.: ' . $e->getMessage();
                            exit;
                    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                            exit;
                    }
                    if (isset($accessToken)) {
                                    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']= $accessToken;
                                    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
                                    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
                                    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']=$longLivedAccessToken;
                                    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
                            try {
                                    $request = $fb->get('/me');
                            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                                    if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
                                            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
                                            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/fb-app/', $permissions);
                                            echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
                                            exit;
                                    }
                            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                                    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                                    exit;
                            }
                            try {
                                    $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email');
                                $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();                                        
                            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                                    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                                    echo "<script>window.top.location.href='https://apps.facebook.com/fb-app/'</script>";
                                    exit;
                            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                                    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                                    exit;
                            }

                            $model->fbvisitor(['name'=>$profile['name'],'email'=>$profile['email'],'id'=>$profile['id']]);
                                    return $this->actionFacebook();
                    } else {
                            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
                            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/fb-app/', $permissions);
                            echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
                    }
```

Below is the error:

> Bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission.
>
> The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
>
> Please contact us if you think this is a server error. 
>   Thank you

Comment: Facebook loads your app into the iframe via a POST request. You need to disable CSRF protection for that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a comment shared by @CBroe I have figured out how to disable CSRF protection for that  specific action. Add  a beforeAction on the Controller and disable CSRFcheck as follows:

```
Public function beforeAction($action)
{   
    if ($this->action->id == 'action-name') {
        Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```